# Router.navigateByUrl("url") not working inside onmessage event from child window in angular13

Tags: angular, window, parent-child

Parent window listening for a message from a child window. but when a message is received I call the router.navigateByUrl("url") function to redirect the user to the dashboard but my parent window gets stuck and does not respond.

I want to redirect the user to the 'dashboard' after getting the message from the child window but when I call router.navigatebyurl('/dashboard') then my parent window gets stuck and is not responding.

This is the submit function calling on the login button.

```
async onSubmit() {
    const logonUri = await this.authService.logon('0').toPromise();

    // Listening for the message
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (!event.data) {
        return;
      }

      let res = AccessTokenViewModel.fromJS({
        access_token: event.data.accessToken,
        expires_in: event.data.expiresIn,
        issued_at: event.data.issuedAt,
      });

      console.log("token response :: ", res);

      // use to process the token response object
      this.onSuccess(res);
    });

    const windowWidth = 500;
    const windowXpos = window.outerWidth / 2 - windowWidth / 2;
    const windowHeight = 700;
    const windowYpos = window.outerHeight / 2 - windowHeight / 2;

    const params = `width=${windowWidth},height=${windowHeight},top=${windowYpos},left=${windowXpos},toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=no`;

    // opening new popup browser window
    this.loginWindow = window.open(logonUri, 'InternalLoginWindow', params);
  }
```

This is onSuccess function which is processing token response.

```
private onSuccess(response: AccessTokenViewModel) {
    this.loader.addState('Login');

    try {
      const helper = new JwtHelperService();
      const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(response.access_token);
      const user = JSON.parse(decodedToken.UserInfo);
      if (user != null) {
        this.store.dispatch(new SetUserToken(response));
        this.store.dispatch(new SetUserInfo(user));
        const formValue = this.loginForm.value;
        if (formValue) {
          const department = this.departments?.find(
            (x) => x.departmentId === +formValue.department
          );
          this.store.dispatch(new SetSelectedDepartment(department));
        }

        // redirect user to the dashboard
        this.navigateToOtherComponent();
      }
    } catch {
      this.helperService.notify(
        Enums.notificationMessageHeader.error,
        'Brugerens e-mail eller adgangskode er forkert',
        Enums.messageType.Error,
        3000
      );
    } finally {
      this.loader.removeState('Login');
    }
  }
```

This below function is used to navigate the user but I'm getting 'Navigation failed or blocked'.

```
  navigateToOtherComponent() {
    this.router
      .navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl)
      .then((navigated: boolean) => {
        if (navigated) {
          console.log('Successfully navigated to /other-component');
        } else {
          console.log('Navigation failed or blocked');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error during navigation:', error));
  }
```

I've tried a lot of different options but still, I'm not able to redirect the user to other components in the parent window when I get the message from the child window. I don't know what the issue is here.

I also redirect the user with window.location.href but it is also not working. parent window not responding.

Comment: why you not use "window.open(<Url>, '_blank')" for redirect another page ? what Do you have try it before ?